# Finding the cosine of an acute angle given the obtuse cosin

Tags: trigonometry

I have the cosine of an obtuse angle and want to find the cosine of the acute angle:
[image]

i.e. I have $\cos{(\theta_{1})}$ how can I find $\cos{(\theta_{2})}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos(\theta_2)=\cos(2\pi-\theta_1)=cos(-\theta_1)=\cos(\theta_1)$

Comment: Hm so why in this question does it say: $\cos{(\theta_{1})} = \frac{-7}{\sqrt{390}}$ so $\cos{(\theta_{2})} = 7\sqrt{390}$? Clearly $\cos_{(\theta_{1})} \not= \cos{(\theta_{2})}$..

Comment: Where we have $\cos(\theta_1)=\frac{-7}{\sqrt{390}}$ in your question?

Comment: yes thats correct

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\theta_2=2\pi-\theta_1$.